# Grouped bar plot R

Tags: r

i have this data frame:

```
  TotalCost Vehicles Bikes
  92        1     2
  92        1     3
  96        1     6
  93        2     2
  93        2     3
  95        2     6
  108       3     2
  108       3     3
  108       3     6
```

I would like to plot with bars filled in 'Bikes' parameter, but this command:

```
ggplot(data, aes(Vehicles, TotalCost)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = Bikes), position = "dodge", stat="identity")
```

gives me this plot, without any color
[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library("magrittr")
library("reshape2")
library("ggplot2")

rawdata = matrix(data =  strsplit(split = ",", "92,1,2,92,1,3,96,1,6,93,2,2,93,2,3,95,2,6,108,3,2,108,3,3,108,3,6") %>% unlist %>% as.numeric,
        ncol = 3, byrow = T)
colnames(rawdata) = c("TotalCost","Vehicles","Bikes")
df = as.data.frame(rawdata, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

If your "Bikes" data are continuous, then you could be looking for the following:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Vehicles, y = TotalCost)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = Bikes), stat="identity")
```

[image]

If the Bikes" are more of distinct categories, then the following might be it:

ggplot(df, aes(x = Vehicles, y = TotalCost)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = as.factor(Bikes)), stat="identity", position = "dodge")

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you can't dodge based on a numeric quantity, because it it continuous.  If you specify `fill=factor(Bikes)` it will do the right thing; otherwise ggplot doesn't know how to "dodge" the bars for a continuous value.

Alternatively, you can specify the grouping explicitly, by adding `group=Bikes` to the aesthetics for the master plot or `geom_bar`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Vehicles, y=TotalCost)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=Bikes, group=Bikes), position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

The advantage of the `factor` approach is that each bar gets its own label, and you can use discrete color scales (like Brewer) to make the differentiation clear.

With the `group` approach, the coloration will reflect the relative values, which may be desirable, but may make the plot hard to read if there are more values for `bikes`, since comparing adjacent `Vehicles` columns will involve comparing subtle gradations.  If we append another row with `108, 3, 7`, then it will be hard to compare the `2` and `3` groupings.

```
ggplot(rbind(df, c(108, 3, 7)), aes(x=Vehicles, y=TotalCost)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=Bikes, group=Bikes), position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: So how should i plot that data frame? Or how can i change the data frame in order to plot a grouped bar?